# Start-Process does not run as expected

Tags: powershell, process, command, admin, privileges

I want to write a PowerShell script to auto-install tools and set up configs after reinstalling OS. Almost command only needs user privilege, but some commands require admin privilege. Therefore, I need create the new progress with admin right and run that command there. I searched Google for that and I found `Start-Progress`

After that, I searched how to get the output of progress started by `Start-Progress`, but I can't find anything. Therefore, I think I need to copy the output to clipboard by using command like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello | clip"' -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

Or write the output to the file like this and read the file to get the output of process:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello > a.log"' -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

The first way runs well. The output as same as this command:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello | clip"
```

But the second way is too weird. It doesn't create file a.log. However, this command runs as I expected:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello > a.log"
```

According to my understanding, the `Start-Process -FilePath "ex.exe" -ArgumentList "some_argument" -Verb RunAs` is the same as we run the command `ex.exe some_argument` but with admin privilege. However, I may be misunderstood `Start-Process` command.

Could you explain it for me? Thank you very much.

I need explanation what differences between
`Start-Process -FilePath "ex.exe" -ArgumentList "some_argument" -Verb RunAs` and `ex.exe some_argument` with admin right

Comment: Try running `Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo $PWD|clip"' -Verb RunAs -Wait`… Then, `Get-Clipboard` answers your question immediately: You could find your file there… Or, add `-NoExit` to the `ArgumentList` string…

Comment: Yes, your command runs well with me as I talk in my question (The problem is not with the clipboard but with writing to the log file). And I found that if I pass more PS commands separated by semicolons like this command ```Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoExit -Command "echo h1 | clip; echo h2 | clip; echo h3 | clip"' -Wait -Verb RunAs``` I only see the ```h3``` in my clipboard (using Win + v)

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello > a.log;(dir a.log).FullName;pause"' -Verb RunAs -Wait`. Then you see *where* the  `a.log` file is created…

Comment: Oh dear, it was created at C:\Windows\System32. Thank you for your answer!
And can I ask you a last question?  I found that if I pass more PS commands separated by semicolons like this command ```Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoExit -Command "echo h1 | clip; echo h2 | clip; echo h3 | clip"' -Wait -Verb RunAs``` I only see the h3 in my clipboard (using Win + v), but if I add ```pause``` after each command I will get all text. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList '-NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "echo hello > a.log;(dir a.log).FullName;pause"' -Verb RunAs -Wait.
```

(Command `echo hello > a.log;(dir a.log).FullName;pause`). Then you see where the `a.log` file is created (supposedly `C:\WINDOWS\system32\a.log`)…

---

**Note**: `echo h1 | clip; echo h2 | clip; echo h3 | clip` utilises [`clip.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html) (the clipboard is overwritten on each use.)

Use [`Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) as follows:

```
echo h1 | Set-Clipboard; echo h2 | Set-Clipboard -append; echo h3 | Set-Clipboard -append
```

Then:

- `Get-Clipboard` returns an array, and
- `Get-Clipboard -Raw` returns a string, with `␍␊` as a delimiter (`[System.Environment]::NewLine`, in fact).

---

To view full Windows clipboard history, press <kbd>Windows logo</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Read [Enumerating Windows clipboard history in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230303-00/?p=107894) as well.